# Parsing POST data with ampersand

Tags: jquery, ajax, serialization, ampersand

A bit of background:  I'm using the jQuery UI sortable serialize method which produces something along the following:

`category[]=Value &amp; One&category[]=ValueTwo&category[]=ValueThree`

I then make an Ajax request to send the data off (POST) to a web service.

I'm currently using the HttpUtility.ParseQueryString method to push the data into a collection, but a problem arises with the & as it results in: "Value" ("& One" is cut off).

This seems like it should be incredibly easy to fix, but for some reason I'm drawing a blank.  What would be the best way to preserve the value as "Value & One"?

**Edit:** Adding code samples:

```
    Dim data As String = "category[]=Value &amp; One&category[]=ValueTwo&category[]=ValueThree"
    Dim httpPOSTData As System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection

    httpPOSTData = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(data)

    'Result: "Value ,ValueTwo,ValueThree"
    'Desired Result: "Value & One,ValueTwo,ValueThree"
```

Javascript:

```
serializedSortOrder =   $('#Categories').sortable('serialize',{
        attribute:'data-category',
        key:'category[]',
        expression: /(.*)/
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery UI is broken. Line 411 of jquery.ui.sortable.js:

```
if(res) str.push((o.key || res[1]+'[]')+'='+(o.key && o.expression ? res[1] : res[2]));
```

Whoops, somebody forgot to `encodeURIComponent()` the key and value parts before dumping into the string.

Comment: Exactly, this is my problem.  Looks like I'm going to have to roll my own serialize for the sortable elements on my page.

Answer (score 1):

It is a problem of the POSTed data, the & should be %-encoded (into %26). And space should be encoded as "+":

```
   category[]=Value+%26+One&category[]=ValueTwo&category[]=ValueThree
```

Comment: Use encodeURIComponent(x) for encoding each parameter. It is builtin method of global object in JavaScript (you can use directly).

Answer (score 0):

Prior to posting your data. You should escape the individual values using any of the native JS escape capabilities.

http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/