# can jQuery serialize() use other separator than ampersand?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I am looking for some nice solution. I've got a couple of textfields on my page and I am sending these via Ajax using jQuery serialize method. This serialized string is parsed in my java method to hashmap with key = 'nameOfTextfield' nad value = 'valueInTextfield'

For example, I've got this String ***stdSel=value1&stdNamText=value2&stdRevText=value3*** and everything works fine.

```
String[] sForm = serializedForm.split("&");
Map<String, String> fForm = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (String part : sForm) {
  String key = null;
  String value = null;
  try {
    key = part.split("=")[0];
    value = part.split("=",2)[1];
    fForm.put(key, value);
  //if textfield is empty
  } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    fForm.put(key, "");
  }
}
```

But this method will break down when ampersand in some textfield appears, for example this ***stdSel=value1&stdNamText=value2&stdRevText=val&&ue3***. My thought was that I'll replace ampersand as separator in searialized string for some other character or maybe more characters. Is it possible and good idea or is there any better way?

Regards
Ondrej

Comment: What do you mean ? Ampersands are escaped (as other special chars) by the serialize function.

Comment: What Java framework are you using?  With any servlet container you shouldn't need to parse the POST parameters yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346877/parsing-post-data-with-ampersand

Comment: I am using Spring 3 MVC pattern. I have one universal javascript function, which sends serialized form from many of different pages. Then I parse it to HashMap and work with it as I need.

Comment: @crowjonah ampersands seem to be escaped : http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/mwWkd/

Comment: So you're saying that you post the serialized parameters as a single parameter?  That's kind-of crazy; there's no reason to do things that way.

Comment: Yes, as a one single parameter :) What is the better way to do this when I've got many textfields in my forms ? Besides of sending it separately because I'm too tired from long javascript ajax queries with twenty parameters.

Comment: Yes, dystroy, you're right. I didn't realize it before. So I'll use my parsing function before using URLdecoder.decode() method. Thank !

Answer (score 0):

Ampersands *are* escaped by the serialize function, so they don't break the URL.

What you need to unescape a field you got from an URL is

```
value = URLDecoder.decode(value,"UTF-8");
```

But, as was pointed by... Pointy,  if you're using a web framework and not using only vanilla java.net java you probably don't have to do this.